# How to convert space and enter key separated input into 2d matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I have an input which contains space and enter key. I want to know how do I map it to a 2d array in python3. I have copy pasted the input.

code:

```
from sys import *
a = stdin.read()
print(type(a))
```

command line:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
<ctrl-D>
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
 matrix = []
 lines = a.split("\n")
 for i in lines:
    matrix.append(i.split(" "))


 print(matrix)
```

Split first for line break. And iterate over the lines and split each line by space and add to the final matrix